# Julia - creating NTuple with a single element

Tags: tuples, julia

I've got a situation where I'm building a struct from NTuples, and it would be convenient if N could equal 1. My experiments in the Julia REPL have not been encouraging. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what problem you have exactly, but here is a way to create 1-element tuple and check if this is a `NTuple{1}`:

```
julia> (1,) isa NTuple{1}
true
```